# Matching exact values of parameter from URL using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Hello friends i have website url ="https://www.example/en_uk/cgid=ladywears&middle=20&end=100"
I need to extract the value of parameter "middle" and "end" which can be any numeric value from 10 to 10000.
Have 1  condition which need to fulfilled --
Url will be  passed dynamically and the program should only run if it has exact "middle" and "end" word matching in it  .Need help in writing it in JavaScript .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to parse the params.

In your real environment, you must use `var url = window.location.search;` to get the current URL. In the below example, I just use your provided URL instead of `window.location.search;`.

```js
// Use window.location.search in your live environment
// var url = window.location.search;

var url = "https://www.example/en_uk/cgid=ladywears&middle=20&end=100";
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(url);
const middle = urlParams.get('middle');
const end = urlParams.get('end');

console.log('middle', middle);
console.log('end', end);
```

Comment: Thanks but is there any way by which we can split the url and extract the value of  end and middle .